# Fixed % width divs not overflowing correctly when page narrows

Tags: html, width, overflow, center, fixed

I understand how everything is supposed to work but I have no idea why it is not working. I am trying to have my page to have two main fixed divs. The left one stays the same at all times and the right one overflow downward when there is more content.

This as of right now works perfectly. The problem is the body or my #bodywrapper divs or anything I make to have a min-width to store the #header and #bodyholder so that when the page shrinks to lower than 1280px horizontally it will require the whole page to overflow/produce a scrollbar so that you can see both the #header and #bodyholder divs. I have attached examples of what I am talking about.

since I do not have 10 rep points yet so here are the links to the images:

correct:
s1190.photobucket.com/user/obancooper/media/ex-correct_zpssnk69nck.png.html

wrong:
s1190.photobucket.com/user/obancooper/media/ex-wrong_zpsszf6kkoj.png.html

To help, the following is the best I can describe in HTML/CSS what the problem is:

html:

```
<div id="bodywrapper">
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="bodyholder">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {   top:18px;
    left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 18%;
    position:fixed;
    margin:0px;}

#bodyholder {width:82%;
min-width:1050px;
right:0px;
overflow:auto;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
}

#bodywrapper {
width:100%;
min-width:1280px;
overflow:scroll;}
```

My site is [pumpingfe.com](http://pumpingfe.com).

Comment: Please edit your question to add meaningful code (the webpage source) and a problem description (as specific as possible) here. Don't just link to the site - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors if it's changed or goes down. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I have since then put an edit to explain my problem simply. I hope the webpage can still act like an example.

Comment: If the link to your site is required to demonstrate the problem, then when you fix the problem, the question will no longer have any future value for new readers. It's OK to have a link, but only as a supplementary i.e. the question would read fine without it. Would you consider replicating the problem in a JS Fiddle, and giving up that link? Also, the key problem description (_the problem is the body div does or my bodywrapper or anything I make to have a min-width for everything is not working properly and the horizontal of everything does not overflow left to right_) is rather confusing.

Comment: I wonder therefore whether you might reword that. In particular, try to avoid "not working properly" (or "does not work" etc) since that does not describe what you expected to happen. Maybe a simple screenshot would assist?

Comment: I have redescribed the problem and provided screenshots. Thanks for looking into it.